# I need a javascript/html plug-in that allows me to post news without editing .html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It would be inconvenient if every time I want to post a news story on my site, I would have to do into my .html file and add the story. Is there a plug-in that allows you to do this from a third party?

Comment: you mean something like wordpress?

Comment: Do you have a server-side language (like PHP)?

Comment: No its purely HTML and javascript

Comment: @MarcusLaszloStromeyer OK, but your server must support a server-side language. Which one do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using some sort of blogging framework, like [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com/), or [Blogger](http://blogger.com). Many shared hosts have plug and play frameworks you can install onto your site. You can customize them too, so it looks more like your site. These frameworks will do all the heavy lifting for you.

You could also check out content management systems like [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/).

Comment: The website was constructed with simple, pure html/javascript coding. I decided not to use a framework. (More fun that way)

Comment: @MarcusLaszloStromeyer - If you want to be able to update anything without having to go to the .html, you need to use some form of a server-side language such as PHP. Client-side code cannot modify server-side html.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you're not using one of the numerous, useful and free content frameworks like Joomla, Wordpress, Blogger, Drupal, etc. to handle this, I would recommend just using jQuery's [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to retrieve your list of articles from the server. You can then use some simple jQuery selectors to insert the content on your page.

**Super simple example (from [Queness](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/ajax/simple.php)):**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getArticle.php",    
  type: "GET",      
  data: data,       
  cache: false,
  success: function (html) {    
    $('#content').html(html);           
  }     
});
```